# Can I code functionality into a viewmodel with MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am always trying to move functionality out of my views and into controllers. Now I have a situation where I have a loop on my page that shows the following data from the view:

```
<a href=
   "@(Model.PageMeta.Url)@string.Format("{0:000}", i)-
           @(Model.Power.PowerDetails[i - 1].Q)">
```

It's messy code for the view and I would prefer to access with a "get" from the viewmodel. One problem is that I would need to pass the value of i back to the viewmodel. Is this possible?

Comment: You could maybe give your ViewMode a method like `MyViewModel.ShowDetail(i)`

Comment: @Giddy - I've not seen this done before. Is that possible. I don't really know how it would be code because I need to send the value of I to the viewmodel.

Comment: Can't you just use the ViewBag?

Comment: Seems like @Muhammad Adeel more or less read me mind! =) +1 Muhammad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't have to use a property when u want to pass a parameter u can use method as suggested by giddy. e.g

```
public class Power {
        public List<PowerDetail> PowerDetails { get; set; }
        public string MetaTag { get; set; }
        public string GetUrl(int index) 
        {
            return this.MetaTag+index+PowerDetails[index-1].Q
        }

    }
    public class PowerDetail 
    {
        public string Q { get; set; }
    }
```

in View you can do like

```
for(int i = 0; i<Model.PowerDetails.Count;i++)
{
    <a href=
   "@(Model.GetUrl(i))"> 
}
```

you have to take care of index out of bound situation and string formatting